# How to remove extra result tag from my SOAP response

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap, asmx

I know this questions has been asked before but I could not find my answer anywhere.

the thing is I have below code on my asmx file:

```
namespace IrancellSmsServer
{
    [SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle = SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]
    [WebService(Namespace =   "http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/data/sync/v1_0/local")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class SoapServer : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public syncOrderRelationResponse syncOrderRelation(
            Sync.UserID userID,
            string spID,
            string productID,
            string serviceID,
            string serviceList,
            int updateType,
            string updateTime,
            string updateDesc,
            string effectiveTime,
            string expiryTime,
            item[] extensionInfo
            )
        {    
            syncOrderRelationResponse a = new syncOrderRelationResponse();
            a.result = 0;
            a.resultDescription = "OK";         
            return a;
        }
     }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <syncOrderRelationResponse xmlns="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/data/sync/v1_0/local">
      <syncOrderRelationResult>   //dont want this
        <result>0</result>
        <resultDescription>OK</resultDescription>
      </syncOrderRelationResult>  //dont want this
    </syncOrderRelationResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope
```

the problem is I dont want that extra `<syncOrderRelationResult>` tag that .net created automatically. I want it completely remove. I have tried [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle=SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]

but no luck it tels me I should have one parameter. is there any way I could do this?

expected result:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
        <syncOrderRelationResponse xmlns="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/data/sync/v1_0/local">
            <result>0</result>
            <resultDescription>OK</resultDescription>
        </syncOrderRelationResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope
```

here is the code of syncOrderRelationResponse:

```
namespace IrancellSmsServer.Sync {
    using System;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.6.1055.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="DataSyncBinding", Namespace="http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/data/sync/v1_0/service")]
    public partial class DataSyncService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {

        private bool useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly;

        /// <remarks/>
        public DataSyncService() {
            this.Url = global::IrancellSmsServer.Properties.Settings.Default.IrancellSmsServer_Sync_DataSyncService;
            if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
            }
            else {
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }
        }

        public new string Url {
            get {
                return base.Url;
            }
            set {
                if ((((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(base.Url) == true) 
                            && (this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly == false)) 
                            && (this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(value) == false))) {
                    base.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                }
                base.Url = value;
            }
        }

        public new bool UseDefaultCredentials {
            get {
                return base.UseDefaultCredentials;
            }
            set {
                base.UseDefaultCredentials = value;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }
        }


        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("syncOrderRelationResponse", Namespace="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/data/sync/v1_0/local")]
        public syncOrderRelationResponse syncOrderRelation([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("syncOrderRelation", Namespace="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/data/sync/v1_0/local")] syncOrderRelation syncOrderRelation1) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("syncOrderRelation", new object[] {
                        syncOrderRelation1});
            return ((syncOrderRelationResponse)(results[0]));
        }


        /// <remarks/>
        public void syncOrderRelationAsync(syncOrderRelation syncOrderRelation1, object userState) {
            if ((this.syncOrderRelationOperationCompleted == null)) {
                this.syncOrderRelationOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnsyncOrderRelationOperationCompleted);
            }
            this.InvokeAsync("syncOrderRelation", new object[] {
                        syncOrderRelation1}, this.syncOrderRelationOperationCompleted, userState);
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1055.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/data/sync/v1_0/local")]
    public partial class syncOrderRelationResponse {

        private int resultField;

        private string resultDescriptionField;

        //private item[] extensionInfoField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public int result {
            get {
                return this.resultField;
            }
            set {
                this.resultField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string resultDescription {
            get {
                return this.resultDescriptionField;
            }
            set {
                this.resultDescriptionField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
        //public item[] extensionInfo {
        //    get {
        //        return this.extensionInfoField;
        //    }
        //    set {
        //        this.extensionInfoField = value;
        //    }
        //}
    }



        /// <remarks/>
        public syncOrderRelationResponse Result {
            get {
                this.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary();
                return ((syncOrderRelationResponse)(this.results[0]));
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you dont want it? what problem it is causing you

Comment: code of syncOrderRelationResponse might also help

Comment: Viru because my client want that.

Comment: post code of syncOrderRelationResponse

Comment: @Viru i added the code

Comment: no I need class from your service side...ths is what class generated using WSDL.....I think you will need to update class from service and regenerate proxy......show me the code form service side for that class

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Add this on top of your method

```
[WebMethod]
[return: XmlElement("syncOrderRelationResponse")]
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this on top of your method

```
[WebMethod]
[return: XmlElement("syncOrderRelationResponse")]
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```

and change it from:

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
```

to :

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
```

and You can also use this link : WOOw!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29855766/8517391

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement and after digging for a while I came with a workaround as follows: 
As mentioned before, in order to remove the result tag, do the following:

```
[WebMethod]
[return: XmlElement("syncOrderRelationResponse")]
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
//the syncOrderRelation method goes here ...
```

This will result in the output as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <syncOrderRelationResponse 
       xmlns="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/data/sync/v1_0/local">
        <result>0</result>
        <resultDescription>OK</resultDescription>
    </syncOrderRelationResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope
```

as you desired. However, It will also strip the method name syncOrderRelation in the request because ParameterStyle is applied to both request and response elements.

Workaround:
Create a Class named syncOrderRelation and put all the parameters from syncOrderRelation request method into the class you just created and use an Object of syncOrderRelation class as a parameter for the method.
Done!

Answer (score 1):

implementing SoapCore (like wcf)
in my case 
write this

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
```

to returned class head and write this

```
[return: XmlElement("availabilityResponse")]
```

to adapter class head

Comment: Are you using XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer? This didn't work for me with DataContractSerilizer, and it caused XmlSerializer to error out.
Adding `[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMember]` to tthe properties of my request/resposne objects fixed *that* error, but then the root element became the first property of my request/response objects.

Comment: See https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore/issues/550 for a longer explanation.

Comment: I remember that it should be datacontract serializor

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove this result. At least it is not documented.

However you can **modify** this name via the return attribute:

[image: An example to name element 'return']

I know this is may not be directly helpful for you (as you want to flatten the structure), but since this is not really a standard way, this can be helpful anyway to know that you can at least modify the name of the result tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to change **`<syncOrderRelationResult>`** to **`<carResult>`**, just add **[XmlRoot("carResult")]** to your object, not your function / method. Here it's sample :

`[XmlRoot("carResult")]
      public class ObjectCar
      {
          public string model;
          public string color;
      }`

or add **[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("carResult")]** to your function / method :

`[WebMethod]
      [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("carResult")]
      public string syncOrderRelation(string a)
      {
          return a;
      }`

2. If you want to change **`<syncOrderRelationResponse ..>`** to **`<YourFunctionName ..>`**, just add **[SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(ResponseElementName = "YourFunctionName")]** to your function / method :

`[WebMethod]
      [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("carResult")][SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(ResponseElementName = "YourFunctionName")]
      public string syncOrderRelation(string a)
      {
          return a;
      }`

hope it's help