# How to remove extra return tags added by SoapCore?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, soapcore

When using SoapCore in .NET Core 3.1 to incorporate the SOAP behavior in my application everything goes as expected, except for the return of two extra tags that inherit the name of the service and provided operation "Response" and "Return" at the end, as can be seen in the image.

```
  <GenerateTokenResult>
   <generateTokenResponse>
```

I have already tested some things as suggested in this other [post] [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238472/how-to-remove-extra-result-tag-from-my-soap-response) but to no avail.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: What's your expected response in the Body node?
normally a soap response would look like this:
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
   <GenerateTokenResponse>
      <GenerateTokenResult>
      
      </GenerateTokenResult>
   </GenerateTokenResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: In my case, I need only the object's tag (in this example GenerateTokenResult, which I rename using the [XmlRoot(ElementName = "NewElementName")]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with extra nesting in XML responses when using SoapCore in ASP.NET Core 6.0. Switching to CoreWCF and using `[MessageContract]` and `[MessageBodyMember]` instead of `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` solved the problem.

Here's what the implementation looked like:

```cs
using CoreWCF;
using CoreWCF.Channels;
using CoreWCF.Configuration;
using CoreWCF.Description;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped<MyService>();
builder.Services.AddServiceModelServices();
builder.Services.AddServiceModelMetadata();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseServiceModel(configure =>
{
    configure.AddService<MyService>()
        .AddServiceEndpoint<MyService, IMyService>(
            new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), 
            "/Service.asmx");

    ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceMetadataBehavior = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
});

app.Run();

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    MyResponse MyRequest(MyRequest myRequest);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public MyResponse MyRequest(MyRequest myRequest)
    {
        return new MyResponse
        {
            OutputMessage = "Hello world"
        };
    }
}

[MessageContract]
public class MyRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string InputMessage { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class MyResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string OutputMessage { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the response comparison:

```xml
// SoapCore
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <s:Body>
    <MyRequestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <MyRequestResult xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ExampleApi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:OutputMessage>Hello world</d4p1:Message>
      </MyRequestResult>
    </MyRequestResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

// CoreWCF
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <MyResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <OutputMessage>Hello world</OutputMessage>
      </MyResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```